# How do I modify custom object attribute with class method

Tags: python, python-3.x

A class in Python 3.6 that keeps track of a set of counts (via nested dictionaries) and a numpy ndarray of the associated probabilities. When I set an element of self.probability to a new value (initialized to 0.0) the mutable attribute does not change.  Using numpy 1.12.

```
import numpy as np


class MatrixClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.tokens = ['x', 'y', 'z']
        self.sequences = [(t1, t2) for t1 in self.tokens for t2 in self.tokens]
        self.p = np.full((len(self.tokens), len(self.sequences)), 0.0)
        self.count = {}
        for t in self.tokens:
            self.count[t] = {}
            for s in self.sequences:
                self.count[t][s] = 0

    def update_probability(self):
        p = self.p
        for i, t in enumerate(self.tokens):
            total = 0
            for j, s in enumerate(self.sequences):
                total += self.count[t][s]
            if total != 0:
                for s in self.sequences:
                    p[i][j] = self.count[t][s] / float(total)
                    if self.count[t][s] > 0:
                        print('****Prob ' + str(i) + ',' + str(j) + ' inner loop: ' + str(p[i][j]))

                if i == 1 and j == 8:
                    print('  Prob ' + str(i) + ',' + str(j) + ' outer loop ' + str(p[i][j]))

        return p

    def update_count(self, data):
        for measure0, measure1 in zip(data, data[1:]):
            token = measure1[0]
            self.count[token][measure0] += 1
        p = self.update_probability()
        self.p = p


m = MatrixClass()
data = [('y', 'y'), ('y', 'z')]
m.update_count(data)
```

Here is the output:

****Prob 1,8 inner loop: 1.0

Prob 1,8 outer loop 0.0

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.  
There is no attribute `probability` in your class; the code is hardly minimal; you've used a variety of one-letter and other generic names that don't facilitate others debugging your code.

Answer (score 0):

The value of self.p in the MatrixClass instance does get changed. The problem is that in the function "update_probability(self)" you set the value of p[1][8] to 1.0 and then back to 0.0 before returning it. By adding a couple of print statements in your update_probability function like below and running it to see the console output can demonstrate the problem

```html
    def update_probability(self):
        p = self.p
        print("p is ", p)
        for i, t in enumerate(self.tokens):
            total = 0
            for j, s in enumerate(self.sequences):
                total += self.count[t][s]

            if total != 0:
                for s in self.sequences:
                    p[i][j] = self.count[t][s] / float(total)
                    print("Setting p[" + str(i) + "][" + str(j) + "] to " + str(self.count[t][s] / float(total)))
                    print("p is equal to ", p , "\n")
                    if self.count[t][s] > 0:
                        print('****Prob ' + str(i) + ',' + str(j) + ' inner loop: ' + str(p[i][j]))

                if i == 1 and j == 8:
                    print('  Prob ' + str(i) + ',' + str(j) + ' outer loop ' + str(p[i][j]))
        return p

***CONSOLE OUPUT***

Setting p[1][8] to 0.0
p is equal to  [[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]] 

Setting p[1][8] to 0.0
p is equal to  [[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]] 

Setting p[1][8] to 0.0
p is equal to  [[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]] 

Setting p[1][8] to 0.0
p is equal to  [[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]] 

Setting p[1][8] to 1.0   ###HERE THE VALUE OF P GETS SET TO 1.0
p is equal to  [[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]] 

****Prob 1,8 inner loop: 1.0
Setting p[1][8] to 0.0
p is equal to  [[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]] 

Setting p[1][8] to 0.0    ###NOW IT IS BACK TO 0.0 and this is the return value you get
p is equal to  [[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]] 

Setting p[1][8] to 0.0
p is equal to  [[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]] 

Setting p[1][8] to 0.0
p is equal to  [[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]] 

  Prob 1,8 outer loop 0.0
```

I suggest that you modify your update_probability method as right now, it only sets the value of p[1][8] to whatever self.count[t][s] / float(total) is equal to. Neither index i nor index j happen to be changing. I suggest that you take a closer look at the indices you are using.

Comment: Thank you, I see the missing enumerate() call now. Not a scope problem after all.